# Splitting chat conversations into sentences and mapping responses

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-mining

I have the following data:

```
Rep: hi ! Customer: i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? Rep: i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options. Customer: ok! thank you Rep: Is there anything else that I can help you with? (Chat ended)
```

I am trying to split this into Q&A format like this:

```
Rep: hi !
Customer: i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? 
Rep: i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options.
Customer: ok! thank you
Rep: Is there anything else that I can help you with?
(Chat ended)
```

This is one set of conversation with an unique ID. After the split I would like to have each the questions and answers as different columns appropriately matching each response.

I tried the following:

```
for i in d.split(':'):
    if i:
        print(i.strip().split('.'))
```

The output is as follows:

```
['Rep']
['hi ! Customer']
['i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? Rep']
["i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options", ' Customer']
['ok! thank you Rep']
['Is there anything else that I can help you with? (Chat ended)']
```

Comment: Probably, you may use [`re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+:.*?(?=\s*[^\W\d_]+:|$)', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/lXuZM7/2)

Comment: Are you only ever having the words "Customer" and "Rep" before the colon, or can it be any unspecified single word like first names? Also, can there be more than one space-delimited word before the colon like "Rep. Johnson: "?

Comment: @AndresSalgado Andres, Yes, I did find different names followed by colon in few other examples too - like "Sam:" "Tom:" etc. But no, there were not any space delimited data

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to identify where you want to insert newlines - as such you could try a couple different patterns, if it's always "customer" and "rep":

`(?<!^)(Customer:|Rep:|\(Chat ended)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yyPtLK/3/)

We just check that we are not at start of the string and then match the constant tokens by OR'ing them together.  Or more generically,

`(?<=\s)([A-Z]\w+:|\(Chat ended)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wwGJBl/5/)

We look back to see a space (we're not at start of string) and then match CapitalizedWord+COLON or ending sequence, then insert newlines before each match.

substitution for both:

`\n$0`

Answer (score 0):

Splitting with `':'` is dangerous because the conversation itself may contain `':'`.

You should have the names of the rep and the customer first so that you can search for their names followed by `:` in a regex pattern, with which you can use `re.findall` to parse the sample chat into:

```
[('Rep', 'hi !'), ('Customer', 'i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ?'), ('Rep', "i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options."), ('Customer', 'ok! thank you')]
```

Then use a loop to map the items into a dict data structure that you prefer:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
def parse_chat(chat, rep, customer):
    conversation = {}
    rep_message = ''
    for person, message in re.findall(r'({0}|{1}): (.*?)\s*(?=(?:{0}|{1}):)'.format(rep, customer), chat):
        if person == rep:
            rep_message = message
        else:
            conversation[rep_message] = message
    return conversation
chat = '''Rep: hi ! Customer: i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? Rep: i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options. Customer: ok! thank you Rep: Is there anything else that I can help you with? (Chat ended)'''
pprint(parse_chat(chat, 'Rep', 'Customer'))
```

This outputs:

```
{'hi !': 'i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ?',
 "i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options.": 'ok! thank you'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a much simpler regex!!!

```
import re

p = re.compile('(\w*\s*:)')

input_string = "Rep: hi ! Customer: i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? Rep: i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options. Customer: ok! thank you Rep: Is there anything else that I can help you with? (Chat ended)"

new_string = p.sub(r'\n\g<1>',input_string)

for line in new_string.split('\n')[1:]:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Based on the assumption that there are only single, non-space-delimited words behind colons, the best approach would be to use regex to match the `Customer` and `Rep` strings before the colons, and then insert newlines so that the appropriate format is obtained.

The following is one working example:

```
import re

# The data has been stored into a string by this point
data = "Rep: hi ! Customer: i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? Rep: i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options. Customer: ok! thank you Rep: Is there anything else that I can help you with? (Chat ended)"

# First insert the newlines before the first word before a colon
newlines = re.sub(r'(\S+)\s*:', r'\n\g<1>:', data)

# Remove the first newline and fix the (Chat ended) on the end
solution = re.sub(r'\(Chat ended\)', '\n(Chat ended)', newlines[1:])

print(solution)

> "Rep: hi ! 
  Customer: i was wondering if you have a delivery option? If so what are the options available ? 
  Rep: i'd be happy to answer that for you! There is a 2 and 5 day delivery options. 
  Customer: ok! thank you 
  Rep: Is there anything else that I can help you with? 
  (Chat ended)"
```

#### Explanation

The `newlines = re.sub...` line first searches the `data` string for any non-space-delimited word followed by a colon, and then replaces it with a `\n` character followed by whatever the sequence of non-space characters was matched, `\S+` (which could be `Customer`, `Rep`, `Bill`, etc.), and then inserts the `:` at the end.

Finally, assuming that all conversations end with `(Chat ended)`, the line of code afterwards matches for only that text and moves it onto a new line in the same manner as the `newlines = re.sub...` line does.

The output is a string, but if you need it to be anything else, you can split it based on `'\n'` and do what you have to do after that.